# Remove elements from key in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key, element

I have a procedure that finds the key that holds the highest number of items in the dictionary. How do i remove the elements in the dictionary so it would only print out

*UPDATE: 
I just found out that my procedure was incorrect. I was trying to find the key that holds the most items, then return the corresponding key

Goal:

> 'd'

```
bird = { 'a': ['Parrot'], 'b': ['Columbidae'], 'c': ['Hummingbird']}

bird['d'] = ['Finch']
bird['d'].append('Owl')
bird['d'].append('Penguin')

def func(a):
    stor =[]
    for itterate in a.items():
        stor.append(itterate)
    return max(stor)


print func(bird)
```

Current output:

> ('d', ['Finch', 'Owl', 'Penguin'])

Comment: `print func(bird)[0]`? or `return max(stor)`?

Comment: Your `max()` function will find the highest key in *alphabetical order*. You may as well use `return max(a)` here.

Comment: I updated my question. I just found out that my procedure was incorrect. I was trying to find the key that holds the most items, then return the corresponding key. @BhargavRao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting the `keys` on the `len()` of their values would get you desired results.

```
>>> bird = { 'a': ['Parrot'], 'b': ['Columbidae'], 'c': ['Hummingbird'], 'd': ['kiwi', 'Crow', 'Sparrow']}

>>> print sorted(bird.keys(), key = lambda x:len(bird[x]))[-1]
>>> d
```

And you could embed this line in your function as :

```
bird = { 'a': ['Parrot'], 'b': ['Columbidae'], 'c': ['Hummingbird']}

bird['d'] = ['Finch']
bird['d'].append('Owl')
bird['d'].append('Penguin')

def func(a):
    return sorted(bird.keys(), key = lambda x:len(bird[x]))[-1]

print func(bird)
```

Or as Padraic suggested, Using the `max` function along with lambda would get your job done in minimal overhead :

```
def func(a):
    return max(bird.keys(), key = lambda x:len(bird[x]))
```

Comment: I want to be able to call the function so it could return the key that holds the most items.

Comment: This is `O(n log n)` and creates a whole new list just to get a one element

Comment: Updated, @PadraicCunningham

Answer (score 0):

Sorting is most certainly not the way to get what you need, you want the key whose value is the longest list so use `max` on `dict.items` using the length of the values as the key to max then return the first element :

```
def func(d):
    return max(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]))[0]
```

Output:

```
In [4]: func(bird)
Out[4]: 'd'
```

You can also do the lookup in the lambda but items is probably the fastest:

```
def func(d):
    return max(d, key=lambda x: len(d[x]))
```